# best practice for Override overload a standard qb-core resource

Tags: lua, fivem

I'm looking for the best way to overwrite or extend a resource in fivem qb-core without ignoring the original resource (OOP like?). I'm thinking of the resource qb--shops as an example. Unfortunately it is written in Lua with no exports or the possibility of overloading. A post drew my attention to "provides" in the manifest.

Unfortunately I can't find any further information or examples and my own attempts have brought nothing. Does anyone know of a best practice
thanxs for help

Answer (score 0):

OOP in Lua means for me: Using Metatables
There is a Metamethod that can magically add functions/methods to every datatype in Lua.
`__index`

```
-- Adding a dir function/method to _G table
_G = setmetatable(_G, {__index={dir = function(this) for k, v in pairs(this) do print(k, '=>', v) end return(this) end}})
```

Impression (Lua 5.1)

```
> _G = setmetatable(_G, {__index={dir = function(this) for k, v in pairs(this) do print(k, '=>', v) end return(this) end}})
> _G:dir()
string  =>  table: 0x5665b660
xpcall  =>  function: 0x56658ce0
package =>  table: 0x56659180
tostring    =>  function: 0x56658a10
print   =>  function: 0x56658470
os  =>  table: 0x5665ad70
unpack  =>  function: 0x56658a90
require =>  function: 0x566596e0
getfenv =>  function: 0x566580d0
setmetatable    =>  function: 0x56658980
next    =>  function: 0x566583f0
assert  =>  function: 0x56657e10
tonumber    =>  function: 0x566589d0
io  =>  table: 0x5665a760
rawequal    =>  function: 0x566584b0
collectgarbage  =>  function: 0x56657e50
getmetatable    =>  function: 0x56658110
module  =>  function: 0x566596a0
rawset  =>  function: 0x56658530
math    =>  table: 0x5665bcb0
debug   =>  table: 0x5665c480
pcall   =>  function: 0x56658430
table   =>  table: 0x56659e70
newproxy    =>  function: 0x56658eb0
type    =>  function: 0x56658a50
coroutine   =>  table: 0x56658f20
_G  =>  table: 0x566575b0
select  =>  function: 0x56658900
gcinfo  =>  function: 0x56658090
pairs   =>  function: 0x56658df0
rawget  =>  function: 0x566584f0
loadstring  =>  function: 0x566583b0
ipairs  =>  function: 0x56658d80
_VERSION    =>  Lua 5.1
dofile  =>  function: 0x56657f20
setfenv =>  function: 0x56658940
load    =>  function: 0x56658370
error   =>  function: 0x56657f60
loadfile    =>  function: 0x56658160
> dir(table)
setn    =>  function: 0x5665a060
insert  =>  function: 0x56659fe0
getn    =>  function: 0x56659f60
foreachi    =>  function: 0x56659f20
maxn    =>  function: 0x56659fa0
foreach =>  function: 0x56659ee0
concat  =>  function: 0x56659ea0
sort    =>  function: 0x5665a0a0
remove  =>  function: 0x5665a020
```

With 'every datatype' i mean this...

```
> -- Adding all math library functions to datatype number as methods/functions
> debug.setmetatable((1), {__index = math})
> print((3.1415926):deg())
179.99999692953
> print((3.14):deg())
179.90874767108
> print((3.14):deg():ceil())
180
```

How it works...
`__index` triggers if that whats called not exists (nil)
So if `_G['dir']` is nil `__index` triggers, found `dir()` and it will be called

PS: Lua holds two datatypes with this technic: userdata and string

```
> io.write(('%s\n%s\n'):format('wake up!', os.date()):upper())
WAKE UP!
THU FEB  9 19:22:37 2023
```

...where string holding all string library functions as methods.

If a Metatable exists on a datatype ( even seted with `debug.setmetatable()` ) than `getmetatable()` can be used to manipulate it (add/remove).

```
> -- Removing __index from DT string
> getmetatable(_VERSION).__index = nil
> io.write(('%s\n%s\n'):format('wake up!', os.date()):upper())
stdin:1: attempt to index a string value
stack traceback:
    stdin:1: in main chunk
    [C]: ?
```

Epilog
Think different.
Put in the qb-core in their related table in an `__index` Metamethod.
Than you can override each of them simply by create a none nil in the qb-core table.
Example: Above `dir()` can simply override by: `_G['dir'] = table.concat`
Remember: dir is now not `nil` (`__index` will not trigger on dir)
...and restored by: `_G['dir'] = nil`
Because the `__index['dir']` will not be affected when doing this.